# Execute procedure if text field is not empty otherwise alert via javascript the message field cannot be empty

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have been struggling to find a method to do this validation and execute my `PL/SQL` procedure.

**Required :**

- Need to check field is empty or not and alert via `javascript field` is empty and my `Dynamic action` should not be executing.
- If my text field is not empty then only my `Dynamic action PL/SQL procedure` should be running.

**My form as below fields :**

```
Subject : `TextField`  -> P1_SUBJECT
Message : `TextField`  -> P1_MESSAGE
Submit  : `Button`     -> property set to -> Execute Validation -> ON
```

**Problem I am facing :**

I have set the property for `Subject  , Message -->  Value required : ON`

Then created dynamic action on `Submit button -> selected option -> Execute server-side code`

In `PL/SQL code` -> written my `PL/SQL` code to send mail

Now without entering values to `Subject  , Message` -> `If I click my Submit button` -> Then also my `procedure gets executed` and mail is sent. This I don't want it to happen .. unless my `Subject` and `Message` field is not empty my procedure should not be triggering.

**Code :**

```
begin
  apex_mail.send(
    p_to   => 'person@exmaple.com',
    p_from => 'me@example.com',
    p_body => :P1_MESSAGE || utl_tcp.crlf,
    p_subj => :P1_SUBJECT);
    
  commit;
end;
```

Any solution is much appreciated  !!!

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to suggest another solution:

Instead of using a dynamic action on submit, create a page process that fires on submit with that same pl/sql code. If the value is required then validation will fail and the page process will not fire.